# How to get device id or any other unique id for each mouse event on Mac

Tags: python, macos, appkit, iokit

I have tried the following code to detect mouse events and also its associated device id / vendor id etc. The value for device id is always 0 for any mouse except the trackpad. Is it possible to find which mouse was used for a mouse event on Mac.

```
from AppKit import NSEvent, NSApplication, NSLeftMouseDownMask, NSLeftMouseUpMask, NSMouseMovedMask

class MouseEventHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = NSApplication.sharedApplication()
        mask = NSLeftMouseDownMask | NSLeftMouseUpMask | NSMouseMovedMask
        NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask_handler_(mask, self.event_handler)

    def event_handler(self, event):
        event_type = event.type()
        device_id = event.deviceID()
        
        if event_type == NSLeftMouseDownMask:
            print(f"Mouse Clicked (Left) on device {device_id}")
        elif event_type == NSLeftMouseUpMask:
            print(f"Mouse Released (Left) on device {device_id}")
        elif event_type == NSMouseMovedMask:
            print(f"Mouse Moved on device {device_id}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    handler = MouseEventHandler()
    NSApplication.sharedApplication().run()
```

**Current Output**

```
Mouse Clicked (Left) on device 5044031582654957 # for touch pad
Mouse Clicked (Left) on device 0.      # for mouse 1
Mouse Clicked (Left) on device 0.      # for mouse 2
```

Is there a way to distinguish between different devices on mac.